# Python - Repeated (second)) value in tuple

Tags: python, list, duplicates

Assuming that my list is as follows:

```
list1 = [('do not care1', 'some string'),
    ('do not care1', 'some new string'),
    ('do not care2', 'some string'),
    ('do not care3', 'some other stringA')
    ('do not care4', 'some other stringA')
    ('do not care10', 'some other stringB')
    ('do not care54', 'some string')
```

I would need the entire entry only if the second value is repeated more than 2 times.

In the above example, I would want to see an output like this

```
'do not care1', 'some string'
'do not care2', 'some string'
'do not care54', 'some string'
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you show your code for this please? What parts of the code are giving you difficulty?

Comment: You may find it easier to use Python's *dictionaries* as opposed to *lists*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.Counter` and a list comprehension :

```
>>> form collections import Counter
>>> [i for i in list1 if i[1] in [item for item,val in Counter(zip(*list1)[1]).items() if val>2]]
[('do not care1', 'some string'), ('do not care2', 'some string'), ('do not care54', 'some string')]
>>>
```